# Subquery returned more than 1 value - where clause

Tags: sql, sql-update, subquery

I have a query to deactivate some accounts that were activated. Basically it looks at the year_end_close table and any accounts that exist there are updated in the master table to an inactive status (A or B).

```
update master
 set account_type = case account_type
  when 'C' then 'A'
  when 'D' then 'B'
  else account_type
 end
where account_num = 
      (select account_num 
       from year_end_close 
       where account_type in('C', 'D'))`
```

I get "Subquery returned more than 1 value" from the where clause - what am I doing wrong? When I comment out the where clause I no longer get that error, so it's something in that clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `=` to `IN`

```
UPDATE master
SET account_type =
   CASE account_type
      WHEN 'C' then 'A'
      WHEN 'D' then 'B'
      ELSE account_type
   END
WHERE account_num IN
(
   SELECT account_num
   FROM year_end_close
   WHERE account_type IN('C', 'D')
)
```

By using the `=` you are saying that you are going to compare 1 item from the left side of the `=` with 1 item from the right side.  There are more than one `account_num` in `year_end_close` with an `account_type` of `C` or `D`.  This makes your sub-query return more than 1 result. The query is unable to determine which value from the sub-query should match the value on the left.  Using the `IN` allows the query to check the left value for any valid `account_num` from your sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

Try an IN rather than checking for equality:

```
update master
 set account_type = case account_type
  when 'C' then 'A'
  when 'D' then 'B'
  else account_type
 end
where account_num IN (select account_num from year_end_close where account_type in('C', 'D'))`
```

...though it rather depends on your data/schema.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers from @matt and @Adam are correct - you need to use `In` rather than `=` if you stick to a subquery.  But I think this is the same as:

```
UPDATE m Set
   account_type = 
    Case account_type
       WHEN 'C' then 'A'
       WHEN 'D' then 'B'
       ELSE account_type END
From master m Join year_end_close c
    On c.account_num  = m.account_num 
       And c.account_type in ('C', 'D')
```

EDIT:  This syntax works in MS Sql Server but may not work in all other vendors' database products.
       Which database are you using?

Comment: This works in `SQL-Server`, but I believe other flavors do not allow the `JOIN` in an `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: @adam, I was not aware of that.. Thanks.

Comment: No problem - I have been burned by providing answers in this format for RDBMS that I was not very familiar with, only to have the OP tell me they didn't work. Your answer is my preferred shape for this type of query when possible.